# Main Nav Dropdown: Can't get it to align properly

Tags: html, css

http://cypresshh.cakuun.com/

I'm building this site out. For the life of me I can't figure out between the padding and the margins how to get the light background box for the dropdown navigation to properly align with the bottom of the header. I've tried padding on the LIs, margin on the LIs, and on the ULs themselves. I think I've been staring at the same problem too long and have hit a wall.

Any help is appreciated greatly.
Thanks
B

Comment: Hi. Try changing padding over here in your css file, ul#main_nav li ul li. Also, use display:block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to list-based menus: **never** use padding or margins on lists items. Use `display:block` on your A-tag and put all formatting there.

Comment: So, I did that and it aligned the sub nav correctly, but I have a huge discrepancy in the width of the main nav when viewed on Safari 5.1.7 on a mac. The main nav flies way out. The nav however looks right in all versions of PC browsers as well as in Safari 5.1.5. Any thoughts?